# Select results from yesterday and a week ago

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I need to select results from my db that were stored yesterday and a week ago. Can I do it n the same query?

```
SELECT *
FROM t1
WHERE DATE(t1recordDate) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

and

```
SELECT *
FROM t1
WHERE DATE(t1recordDate) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

Comment: Did you try to use `OR`?

Comment: Apparently OR is not the only solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `or` logical operator, or better yet, the shorthand `in`:

```
SELECT *
FROM   t1
WHERE  DATE(t1recordDate) IN 
       (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY, CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use OR and date_sub  if you need  only the value for yesterday and a wekk ago  but not for the days in range

```
SELECT *
FROM t1
WHERE DATE(t1recordDate) = DATE(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY))
OR DATE(t1recordDate) = DATE(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 7 DAY))
```

and if you need  all the range

```
SELECT *
FROM t1
WHERE DATE(t1recordDate) BETWEEN  DATE(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 7 DAY))
       AND  DATE(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY))
```

Comment: No need for ranges, just need exact matches. "URDATE" is it a typo?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like the trivial solution you can try this one:

```
select t1.*
from (
    select 
        curdate() - interval 1 day as ts_from,
        curdate() - interval 1 second as ts_to
    union all
    select 
        curdate() - interval 7 day as ts_from,
        curdate() - interval 6 day - interval 1 second as ts_to
) as r
join t1 on t1.t1recordDate between r.ts_from and r.ts_to
```

http://rextester.com/PLVMY63927

It can at least use an index.